# How do I concatenate two images in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two `UIImageView`'s, and I want to concatenate them both to be one `UIImageView`. To let you know, the images have some transparency to them so you will see both of them. Als they are the same size.

Comment: When you say concatenate, do you mean overlay them (put them in the same place) or put them next to each other?  If you mean overlay, what do you want to happen when two pixels are at the same spot -- how do you want transparency to be handled?

Comment: I want to make them one `UIImageView`,  and yes they are the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey if you are using two static image-views then you can do the this by taking the screen-shot with this code

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
 UIImage *savedImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();//here is the final image
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 [pool release];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overlay one imageView over another, just set its backgroundColor to clear and move it over, either using IB or directly setting its frame via code.